# Tinyproxy not forwarding requests. Getting Unauthorized connection from <IP>

Tags: configuration, proxy, proxy-server

I have installed tinyproxy in CentOS 7 machine and changed the port to 8080 in tinyproxy.conf
Wherenever I am hitting request I am getting following logs in tinyproxy.log:-

```
CONNECT   Mar 15 08:14:42 [22148]: Connect (file descriptor 6): <IP> [<IP>]
NOTICE    Mar 15 08:14:42 [22148]: Unauthorized connection from "<IP>" [<IP>].
INFO      Mar 15 08:14:42 [22148]: Read request entity of 1200 bytes
```

My request is reaching to proxy and proxy is not forwarding it to the destination.

Answer (score 16):

In the Tinyproxy config file `(/etc/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.conf)` you can use the Allow directive to explicitly specify the host(s) that will be connecting to the proxy. You can also comment out or remove all `Allow <host>` lines to allow connections from all hosts. See below description from the config file (here I've commented out `Allow 127.0.0.1` and since there are no other entries all connections will be allowed):

```
# Allow: Customization of authorization controls. If there are any
# access control keywords then the default action is to DENY. Otherwise,
# the default action is ALLOW.
#
# The order of the controls are important. All incoming connections are
# tested against the controls based on order.
#
#Allow 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set it like this (`tinyproxy.conf`):

```
Allow 0.0.0.0/0
```